# Looking for a cool underground race

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monsters, races

I'm a young DM and the course of events will most likely lead my players to an underground region (unexplored caves in which they ran to escape a prison).
At first my thought was to lead them in the open after some short encounter, but I got this idea of an underground village of an ancient race that was confined there many years ago.

Here's my question: which race do you think would be cool in this kind of situation?

My first idea was a Drow village (that make sense because that region was dwelt bg elves) but I picture them as a smart and cunning race, while the village was forbid from any contact with the overworld.  So I'm still looking for a less smart race, maybe something akin to rocks like goliath for example.

Comment: Hi YED, I've closed this since it falls afoul of our [questions to avoid asking](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). RPG.SE works best when we handle questions that can have a best or correct answer, and we don't handle pure opinion surveys -- since every answer is equally valid and there's no best/correct answer our voting system doesn't work or have relevance there. You can however ask this question on a forum, [such as one of these we've collected a list of](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449). Since you have 20+ rep you also have the option of joining us in [chat] to ask.

Comment: The question's title might be throwing off readers. It sounds like what you *really* want are creatures that can survive and thrive without outside contact… underground. Were the question rephrased to emphasize *that* and included something like *The creatures' official fluff must support this use of the creatures in the campaign, making reskinning, for example, inappropriate*, I think it'd be possible for answers to develop a reasonable, constrained list of appropriate creatures.

Comment: Yeah it'd work better if it was asking "what races could actually survive in these conditions and work with this concept?", rather than "what race do you think would be cool?" I mean, I think dwarves are cool, so I could say they'd be cool for that situation, and every other race will eventually get listed because someone thinks it's cool. But that's different to whether they might work. (Even Kender would eventually be suggested as cool for that situation, since I'm sure several people will be a fan of trapping Kender underground isolated from the outside world forever.)

Comment: Well the title was ambigous because I was open also to ideas very different from mine. But as dopplegreener said, I should ask personal opinions on the forum. So thanks for the aswers and for the clarification on the title, hope next time I'll be more precise on the title.

Comment: You don't have to wait until next time. You can still edit *this* question—both its content and its title—so that it meets the site's guidelines.

Comment: Please reopen I have an answer.

Comment: @MrHiTech Your edit in no way made the question a better fit for the site. It's still completely opinion based, without a valid "best answer". Mindflayer, Duargar, Earthworm Jim, they'd all be equally valid answers and there's no way to determine what the "right one" is.